# Why using two IPEndPoint?

Tags: c#, sockets, msdn

I am creating a UDP Server.I found following code reference from MSDN.Can any one please explain why they are using two IPEndPoint objects in the code sample.I assume second ipeEdpoint is the address of sender(Client). But how it is possible? Ip address of client can be extract from the Data gram packet, So what is the purpose for the second object here?This may be a simple and silly question but i am little confusing...:D

```
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];

  IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

  UdpClient newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);

  Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

  IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

  data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? [UdpClient.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx): "This method populates the remoteEP parameter with the IPAddress and port number of the sender."

Comment: @dtb Thanks but..please clear this one..Server don't know IP of sender until it receives the Packets.So how can we use predefined remote ip end point to call the receive method.

Comment: The remoteEP is returned by reference: [ref (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx). You pass in some IPEndPoint and when the method returns, the variable contains the IPEndPoint of the sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to the `UdpClient` constructor passes in the hosts end point.  Receive starts the process of receiving data--which won't do anything until another process makes a request to the end point you created in the `UdpClient` constructor.  When that connection *does* happen, the endpoint of the process sending data to your `UdpClient` will then be available.  e.g. in the `sender` variable.